# spring filters applies to all api urls Errors

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

i am new to spring  security,problem is that filter is applied to all request urls i-e. `/api/user/signup`. i want to exclude `/api/user/signup` path to go through the filter. i even tried following

```
web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**")
            .antMatchers("/api/user/signup")
```

but filter again applied to it. Filter requires authkey token and signup request
obvously will have no token. and it will through exception when it don't finds the token.Following is spring security java config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authenticationTokenFilter;
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
    .antMatchers("/api/user/**")
    .antMatchers("/api/user/signup")

    ;
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()   

    //allow anonymous POSTs to login
    .antMatchers("/api/user/signup").permitAll()

    //allow anonymous GETs to API
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)     
    .and()
     .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)    
      ;
}
```

and here is my token filter class

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

  //  @Autowired UserService userService;
   @Autowired 
   TokenHandler tokenUtils;
   @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        this.authManager = authManager;
    }

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

        if (context.getAuthentication() != null && context.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()) {
            // do nothing
        }else {

            //System.out.println("Not Authenticated");
        if(req != null && req.getHeader("authKey") != null && req.getHeader("authKey").length() >0 ) {
            String token = req.getHeader("authKey"); 
           System.out.println("Found Token:"+req.getHeader("authKey"));
            // validate the token
            User userDetails = tokenUtils.parseUserFromToken(token);

                     List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
                     grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                     Authentication  authentication = 
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getEmail(), userDetails.getPassword(),grantedAuths);

                // set the authentication into the SecurityContext

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);         


           System.out.println("Is Authenticated:?"+  context.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());
        // continue thru the filter chain
           chain.doFilter(request, response);
           System.out.println(" request is delegeted");
        }else{ 

                // Do your business stuff here for all paths other than /specialpath.
                System.out.println(" Token Not Found");
                throw new ServletException("Token not found in Request");           

        }

    }
}
```

following is error log when `/api/user/signup` comes

```
Token Not Found
2015-05-17 09:38:36.742 ERROR 5096 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Token not found in Request] with root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Token not found in Request
    at com.bitsparlour.sadaf.cloud.application.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to mimic the good old namespace way of having multiple `<http ...>` blocks. With Java configuration, you can also have multiple classes extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Spring Security Reference Manual has an [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity) for that. Extracts :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
        ...
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        2
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
                ...
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   4
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .formLogin()
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Notes :

1. Configure `Authentication` as normal
2. Create an instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that contains `@Order` to specify which `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be considered first.
3. The `http.antMatcher` states that this `HttpSecurity` will only be applicable to URLs that start with `/api/`
4. Create another instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. If the URL does not start with `/api/` this configuration will be used (no `@Order` defaults to last)

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions is to skip filter logic depending on incoming URL.
Just after the line:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
```

in the method `doFilter` of your `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` add this code:

```
if (new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/signup").matches(req))) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    return;
}
```

And of course it's not a good practice to hardcode the URL inside of `doFilter` method - you can pass that URL to your filter from `SecurityConfig.configure` method. Also `new AntPathRequestMatcher` could be optimised - just create it once and put in a field variable.

Answer (score 0):

By annotating your filter with '@Component', you are telling Spring to add it to the embedded container.

> Any Servlet, Filter or Servlet *Listener instance that is a Spring bean will be registered with the embedded container. This can be particularly convenient if you want to refer to a value from your application.properties during configuration.

So `.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)` this line has no impact.

To fix it, remove the @Component and @Autowired and construct your own instance and don't make it a bean.